# Volume Control Not Working in my App

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a game and when the game is playing the volume control is not working. Can anyone give me the solution?

It is in AndEngine

Comment: which code?? I dont want to do this programatically. The volume control hardware button on right top side of device is not working in my app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution. Where the keycodes are handled return false and volume will start working. I was handling back button and returning true in all cases there. So what I did was that I returned true only when keypressed is back else return false and my problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

There are four kind of sound setting in android 1)Alarm 2)Music 3)Ring Tone 4)Notification
First Create object of AudioManager amanager;
IF you want to set Volume use this code

For Notification

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Alerm

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Music

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

For Ring Tone

```
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Comment: I don't want to set the volume pragmatically.
In all other apps the volume button on the left top side of the device its working but in my app its not working. I want solution for this problem. I don't want to set in programatically I want to set it via volume button press

Comment: there isnt any code I wrote for volume. The code is a full fledge app actually. In other apps the volume button is working but in this app its not working. I dont understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I override onKeyDown and not properly handling volume keys, my solution is this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    boolean ret = super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
        || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
        || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE) {
        return ret;
    }
    return handleKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```